# Combine europecv document class with KOMA-script letter scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, letters, europecv

I use the document class `europecv` to write my CV. I want to add a letter before the actual CV, most preferable with the `scrlttr2` KOMA-script document class.

Is there a way to load the KOMA-script document class `scrlttr2` as a package, or can anyone recommend another way of having both - a CV and a letter - in the same document?

Comment: Do you need a `.pdf` file to be sent or two separate documents to be printed out?

Comment: I need one single PDF containing both, the CV and the letter. Maybe I'll just create two separate documents and include in into the other using `includepdf`...

Comment: A combination of both classes is most probably not possible, since `letter` classes have very restrictive format, disabling many features you might prefer using from your `europecv` class. Please post a MWE in order to give some clue, what can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution that comes to mind is just putting different pdf together using package `pdfpages`.

With version 3.15 of KOMA-Script, which is [available at the develepors homepage](http://www.komascript.de/current), it is possible to include features of a letter within the other KOMA-classes.

We have seen in the past, that `europecv` has some limitations. An alternative could be `komacv`. Following an example (stolen from the `komacv` docs) of letter features with `scrartcl` (which is working under the hood of `komacv`). If anybody wonders, yes, the appearance looks similar to `moderncv`.

[image: komaLetter0]

And the CV on the following page:

[image: komaLetter1]

```
%komacv still uses the obsolet scrpage2
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\ReplacePackage{scrpage2}{scrlayer-scrpage}
%We simply replaced it with its successor
\documentclass{komacv}
\renewcommand*{\title}{CV}
\renewcommand*{\firstname}{Jane}
\renewcommand*{\familyname}{Eyre}
\renewcommand*{\acadtitle}{B.\,Ed.}
\renewcommand*{\addressstreet}{Ferndean House}
\renewcommand*{\addresscity}{Ferndean Village}
\renewcommand*{\address}[2]{\addressstreet{#1}\addresscity{#2}}
\renewcommand*{\mobile}{009-87654321}
\renewcommand*{\phonenr}{001-23456789}
\renewcommand*{\faxnr}{001-23456788}
\renewcommand*{\email}{jeyre@ferndean.me.uk}
\renewcommand*{\extrainfo}{Some extra info}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrletter}
%\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{\firstname~\familyname}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\addressstreet\\\addresscity}
\begin{letter}{hallo}
    \opening{Dear Sir,}
    \blindtext
    \closing{Farewell}
\end{letter}
\maketitle

\section{Personal Information}
\cvitem{Date of birth}{February 15, 1828}
\cvitem{Nationality}{British}
\cvitem{Civil Status}{Married, two children}

\section{Education}
\cventry{1835--1838}{Homeschooling}{}{Gateshead}{grades
1--3}{Teacher: Mr.~NN, under supervision of my aunt Ms. Reed.}
\cventry{1838--1844}{Lowood School}{}{Lowood}{grades 3--8}{A
    charitable institution under the guidance of
Mr.~Brocklehurst.}

\section{Work}

\subsection{Teaching}
\cventry{1844--1846}{Teacher}{Lowood School}{Lowood}{}{Teaching
all grades.}
\cventry{1846--1847}{Governess}{}{Thornfield Hall, Thornfield
near Millcote}{}{Governess of Mr.~Rochester's ward Adèle,
10~years old.}
\cventry{1847}{Village teacher}{girl's school}{Moore
village}{}{Teaching all village girls, mostly farmer's daughters,
all grades.}
\cventry{1849--1867}{Home schooling}{}{Ferndean}{}{Educating and
teaching my children, a son and a daughter.}

\subsection{Nursing}
\cventry{1847\,ff.}{Nursing my physically impaired
husband}{}{}{}{Very poor eyesight and one hand amputated due to a
fire.}

\subsection{Management}
\cventry{1847\,ff.}{Management of the family
estate}{}{}{}{Including the household at Ferndean and extensive
property in England and on the continent.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `komacv` could use a little refreshment, even though it is quite new. I am going to send a mail to the developer.