# Why do I have three lines on the very left of my page?

Tags: koma-script, line-spacing, scrlttr2

I am currently creating a cover letter (using a template) but I cannot find out why I have those three lines on the very left of my page. They seem to be aligned with something, but I cannot figure out with what.

Comment: Welcome to TEX SE! Please provide a complete example that we can copy and process. Otherwise, we cannot effectively help you.

Comment: One has to guess that the mystery template draws the lines.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) 
Here is the code, the comments are in German though. But you can see on the very left, there are 3 lines

Comment: ohh it says my comment is way too big :( 

I pasted it here:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hsS7Hxue

Comment: You can edit your question to include the file rather than use pastebin or try to update it via comments.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the folding marks? (See my answer below). If so, the upper and lower mark show you where to fold your letter to insert into a standard C6/C5 envelope, while the slightly longer line denotes the middle of the page height, allowing you to align a standard two-hole punch with ease. Many (European, I presume) professional letters feature these marks.

Answer (score 3):

I am taking a wild guess here, but I think he's referring to the folding / punch marks on the left margin. To turn them off, simply use

`\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=off}`

in the preamble.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're referring to when you talk about "those three lines" I'm guessing it's the circled text from the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of LaTeX output]

This is the addressee of the letter, and the positioning is determined by the `scrlttr2` class (I removed all the option setting to make sure that this was the default behavior and then verified by finding another example of the output of `scrlttr2` here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218566/202780